# an infinite monoid that is not free monoid and does not contain any free monoid

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups, monoid, monoidal-categories, free-abelian-group

Let $H$ generated by some generators $H=\langle h_1, \ldots, h_n\rangle$ $(n\gt 1)$. My question is whether there exists any monoid $H$ such that $H$, is infinite and $H$ is not a free monoid and $H$ does not contain any free monoid?

Comment: Please use MathJax.

Comment: I don't know about monoids, but for groups this is an open problem:  see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78410/finitely-presented-infinite-group-with-no-element-of-infinite-order.

Comment: The OP does not require a finite presentation. The [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4108919/infinite-monoid-h-that-is-not-a-free-monoid-and-contains-a-free-monoid-as-a-subm/4109191#4109191) was closed and is now upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

The paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.01695 gives a finitely presented semigroup with zero satisfying $x^9=0$ for all $x$. Adjoining an identity would give a monoid. The paper is not published and in Russian.  This was a famous question.

Answer (score 2):

Let $M$ be the quotient of the free monoid $\{a,b\}^*$ by the relations $x^3y = yx^3 = x^3$, for all words $x$ and $y$. This is a monoid with zero in which $x^3 = 0$ is an identity. To prove it is infinite, consider the [Prouhet-Thue-Morse infinite word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence). This infinite word is known to be *cube-free*, which means that it contains no factor of the form $uuu$, where $u$ is a nonempty word. It follows that each finite prefix of this infinite word corresponds to an element of $M$, and thus $M$ is infinite.